# Unity3D (2D): как сделать разваливающийся спрайт?

Tags: unity3d, 2d

У нас есть 2D авто, соответственно собранное из спрайтов, чтобы та могла распадаться (как это думалось в теории):

[image: мой Plymouth 1970]

Как сделать авто разрушаемым, т.е. при воздействии силы на какую-то часть автомобиля эта часть отлетала с учетом RigidBody2D???

P.S. пытался дать каждой части RigidBody, потом связал все части FixedJoint2D, якоря сместил в одну точку, значения выставил. Части то держались, но якоря всё равно расходились, как и части машины и образовывали зазоры.